# Find a paragraph and find a string inside this paragraph with REGEX

Tags: python, html, regex, html-parsing

I have inside an HTML page some lines like this :

```
<div>
    <p class="match"> this sentence should match </p> 
    some text
    <a class="a"> some text </a>  
</div>
<div> 
    <p class="match"> this sentence shouldnt match</p> 
    some text
    <a class ="b"> some text </a> 
</div>
```

I want to extract the lines inside the `<p class="match">` but only when there are inside `div` containing `<a class="a">`.

What I've done so far is below (I firstly find the paragraphs with `<a class="a">` inside and I iterate on the result to find the sentence inside a `<p class="match">`) :

```
import re
file_to_r = open("a")

regex_div = re.compile(r'<div>.+"a".+?</div>', re.DOTALL)

regex_match = re.compile(r'<p class="match">(.+)</p>')
for m in regex_div.findall(file_to_r.read()):
    print(regex_match.findall(m))
```

but I wonder if there is an other (still efficient) way to do it at once?

Comment: Try beautiful soup 4 for parsing html files..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a html parser but if you still wat a regex you can use something like this:

```
<div>\s*<p class="match">([\w\s]+)</p>[\w\s]+(?=<a class="a").*?</div>
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/pV9qY8/1)**

[image]

Comment: @Jerry as I suggested in my answer I wouldn't use a regex to parse html. But I posted the answer as an option to reply the question using a regex.

Answer (score 3):

Use an HTML Parser, like [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

Find the `a` tag with `a` class and then [find previous sibling](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-previous-siblings-and-find-previous-sibling) - `p` tag with class `match`:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<div>
    <p class="match"> this sentence should match </p>
    some text
    <a class="a"> some text </a>
</div>
<div>
    <p class="match"> this sentence shouldn't match</p>
    some text
    <a class ="b"> some text </a>
</div>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
a = soup.find('a', class_='a')
print a.find_previous_sibling('p', class_='match').text
```

Prints:

```
this sentence should match
```

Also see why you should avoid using regex for parsing HTML here:

- [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: @user3683807 please read the linked thread carefully - html parsers are being made specifically for parsing HTML - specific tools for a particular task. I would recommend use `BeautifulSoup` here - it makes HTML parsing easy and reliable.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div>\s*\n\s*.*?<p class=.*?>(.*?)<\/p>\s*\n\s*.*?\s*\n\s*(?=(\<a class=\"a\"\>))
```

You can use this.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lK9iD2/7